# Como travar um layout na ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE e outra na ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

Tags: java, android

Estou utilizando o método para quando mudar de posição troca de  layout porém quando inicio aplicação em paisagem ele inicia o layout teste_01 modo paisagem sendo que seu formato é retrato como corrigir isso.

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste_02);
    inicializarInterface();
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste_01);
    inicializarInterface();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar da pasta `res` para criar layouts específicos para portrait ou landscape.

A pasta `layout` dentro da pasta `res`, serve para layouts genéricos, sem "tratamento" algum, para todo tipo de tela (resolução ou orientação).

Caso você queira criar um layout específico para portrait, basta criar uma pasta `layout-port` dentro da sua pasta `res`.
E, para criar um layout específico para landscape, crie uma pasta `layout-land` dentro de sua pasta `res`.

**Nota**: não esqueça de manter o mesmo nome para os ambos os layouts em ambas as pastas.

Em sua `Activity` você não precisa se preocupar com qual `layout` será inflado, chamando apenas `setContentView(R.layout.seu_layout)` e deixar o Android cuidar do resto

Para mais detalhes, siga a documentação oficial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: @Rodolfo é apenas de exemplo! Você precisa implementar o layout (arquivo .xml) que você criou.

Comment: @Rodolfo qual o nome do arquivo .xml que você criou em cada pasta?

Comment: @Rodolfo pois bem. Depois de ter criado sua `activity_teste.xml` na pasta `layout-land` e/ou na pasta `layout-port`, em sua `Activity` coloque `setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);`

Comment: valeu já encontrei meu erro

Comment: @Rodolfo ótimo! Aconselho a dar uma lida/estudada em como funciona a pasta `res` do Android para você conseguir utilizar todo o seu potencial

Comment: tenho uma duvida se achar melhor abro outra pergunta como fazer para que não fique inicializando quando mudar de layout de paisagem para retrato e vice versa tipo, ficar em moda espera não sei se deu para entender.

Comment: @Rodolfo nao consegui entender. Abra outra pergunta e detalhe melhor a pergunta com o que voce precisa por favor

Comment: já publiquei um nova pergunta.